# jQuery AJAX complete handler

Tags: jquery, facebox

I have table that shows some records from database.
each table has a column that shows detail for target column.
I want to show detail in facebox popup.
each detail came from AJAX request.
first time that I click on a row It shows empty facebox.
I wrote facebox code on complete handler of my ajax request.
and next times that I clicking on rows It shows data about previous clicks.
What's wrong?
Its simple form of my code :

```
 $(function () {

        $(".view").click(function (e) {
            var props = [{ 'Key': 'FilledFormID', 'Value': 4}];

            var fileName = "~/Maskan/Control/UserDiscussions.ascx";

            var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ path: fileName, properties: props });
            $("#test").advloaduc({
                webServiceName: '../../Services/AJAX.asmx',
                renderUCMethod: 'RenderUserControl',
                ucMethodJsonParams: jsonText,
                completeHandler: jQuery.facebox({ div: '#test' })


            });
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you code like so.

Original Code:

```
$("#test").advloaduc({
    webServiceName: '../../Services/AJAX.asmx',
    renderUCMethod: 'RenderUserControl',
    ucMethodJsonParams: jsonText,
    completeHandler: jQuery.facebox({
        div: '#test'
    })
});
```

New Code:

```
$("#test").advloaduc({
    webServiceName: '../../Services/AJAX.asmx',
    renderUCMethod: 'RenderUserControl',
    ucMethodJsonParams: jsonText,
    completeHandler: function() {
        jQuery.facebox({
            div: '#test'
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Would you please describe about problem of my code?

Comment: The complete handler expects a `function()` to be passed into it, what you passed in was a statement.